# Datagrip: Create postgres index without waiting for execution

Tags: postgresql, indexing, datagrip

Is there a way to submit a command in datagrip to a database without keeping the connection open / asynchronously? I'm attempting to create indexes concurrently, but I'd also like to close my laptop.

My datagrip workflow:
Select column in a database, click 'modify column', and eventually run code such as:

```
create index concurrently batchdisbursements_updated_index
    on de_testing.batchdisbursements (updated);
```

However, these run as background tasks and cancel if I exit datagrip.

Comment: Perhaps a viable solution is to change your what your laptop does when you close it. Change the setting to simply ignore the fact it's now closed.As you didn't specify your operating system see for [Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/412876/how-to-keep-your-laptop-on-with-the-lid-closed-on-windows-10/) and for [Linux](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) (Ubuntu 18.04LTS) (other Linux distros should have similar functionality)

Comment: Turns out if you create concurrently or create synchronously, you can cancel the command after a few seconds and the command will have already been submitted to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, these run as background tasks and cancel if I exit datagrip.

What if you close your laptop without exiting datagrip?  Datagrip is probably actively sending a cancellation message to PostgreSQL when you exit it.  If you just close the laptop, I doubt it will do that. In that case, PostgreSQL won't notice the client has gone away until it tries to send a message, at which point the index creation should already be done and committed.

But this is a fragile plan.  I would ssh to the server, run `screen` (or one of the fancier variants), run `psql` in that, and create the indexes from there.